# Naming Var using Var

Tags: ruby, arrays, hashmap

I'm trying to create arrays dynamically and am messing with this code, but I'm not getting anywhere.

Starting with `locations`:

```
locations = {"boston" => 1, "new_york" => 2 , "miami" => 3}
```

And using:

```
locations.each {
|city, id|  puts "#{city}_angels"
}
```

The desired outcome is to initialize three arrays: `boston_angels`, `new_york_angels`, `miami_angels`.

Comment: Do they need to be local variables? Why not have an `angels` hash which contains `boston`, `new_york`, and `miami` keys?

Comment: I suppose a hash w/ arrays as its values could work. How would you initialize the empty arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments on the question, there are lots of way to construct a hash from a source enumerable. `each_with_object` is one of my favorites:

```
locations.keys.each_with_object({}) {|city, out| out[city] = [] }
```

`inject`/`reduce` is another option:

```
locations.keys.inject({}) {|h, city| h[city] = []; h }
```

You could also create an array of `[city, []]` arrays, then convert it to a hash:

```
Hash[*locations.flat_map {|city, id| [city, []] }]
```

Or if you're using Ruby 2.1:

```
locations.keys.map {|k| [k, []] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 1):

The question has nothing to do with the values of the hash `location`, so let's start with:

```
cities = locations.keys
  #=> ["boston", "new_york", "miami"]
```

Three other ways to do this:

**#1**

```
Hash[cities.map { |c| [c, []] }]
  #=> {"boston"=>[], "new_york"=>[], "miami"=>[]}
```

With Ruby 2.1+ you can write `Hash[arr]` as `arr.to_h`.

**#2**

```
cities.reduce({}) { |h,city| h.merge({ city=>[] }) }
```

**#3**

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
h.values_at(*cities)
h
  #=> {"boston"=>[], "new_york"=>[], "miami"=>[]}
```